# Android: hardware.Camera focus method doesn't work with some devices

Tags: android, camera, focus

I'm using these methods to activate the on Touch focus on SurFaceView

```
private SurfaceView surfaceiew;
private CameraSource camSource;
private Camera camera;
private Camera.Parameters params;



private void initCameraFocusListener() {
    surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            cameraFocus(event, camSource, Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

            return false;
        }
    });

}




// camera focus method
private boolean cameraFocus(MotionEvent event, @NonNull CameraSource cameraSource, @NonNull String focusMode) {
    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();


    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
    int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
    // Get the pointer's current position
    float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
    float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

    float touchMajor = event.getTouchMajor();
    float touchMinor = event.getTouchMinor();

    Rect touchRect = new Rect((int)(x - touchMajor / 2), (int)(y - touchMinor / 2), (int)(x + touchMajor / 2), (int)(y + touchMinor / 2));

    Rect focusArea = new Rect();

    focusArea.set(touchRect.left * 2000 / surfaceView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.top * 2000 / surfaceView.getHeight() - 1000,
            touchRect.right * 2000 / surfaceView.getWidth() - 1000,
            touchRect.bottom * 2000 / surfaceView.getHeight() - 1000);

    // Submit focus area to camera

    ArrayList<Camera.Area> focusAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
    focusAreas.add(new Camera.Area(focusArea, 1000));

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFocusMode(focusMode);
                    params.setFocusAreas(focusAreas);
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                    // Start the autofocus operation

                    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
                            // currently set to auto-focus on single touch
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }



    return false;
}
```

it's working perfectly on most devices , but i found out that it's not working on Huawei Honor 5x which uses Android 5.0 version.

the weird part is the method instead of doing its job , it takes me to previous page(activity) .

How to do the on Touch Auto Focus with CameraSource And SurfaceView correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess the problem is because I'm using a Deprecated class : Camera